# Processing multiple input fields with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, input

The problem I am having is that my ecommerce script allows people to add products to their store. However, those products can have variants... like Color and those variants can have options, like Black, White, and Blue for example. The problem I am having is how exactly do I determine how many options they have entered. Eventually I will have a javascript function add a new input field if they click "add option" but for now I just made 3 input fields like so:

```
Variant Title:<input type="text" name="variant_title"><br>
Variant Option: <input type="text" name="variant_option_1"><br>
Variant Option: <input type="text" name="variant_option_2"><br>
Variant Option: <input type="text" name="variant_option_3"><br>
```

Now what I don't know how to do is loop through all the variant_options and if they are not empty add them to a database. I don't want to hard code it in with the names because I don't know how many options they will choose per variant.

I tried doing this:

```
$i = 1;
            while($this->input->post('variant_option_$i') != '')
            {
                $variant_options[] = $this->post->input('variant_option_$i');
                $i++;
            }
```

But that does not seem to work, as the variant title gets added to the database, however the options do not.

The only thing I need a solution to is to how to actually grab those fields all at once. I was thinking a foreach loop but im not sure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an array of input fields instead:

```
Variant Title:<input type="text" name="variant_title"><br>
Variant Option: <input type="text" name="variant_option[]"><br>
Variant Option: <input type="text" name="variant_option[]"><br>
Variant Option: <input type="text" name="variant_option[]"><br>
```

Then check for the values like:

```
if (is_array($this->input->post('variant_option')):
   foreach ($this->input->post('variant_option') as $value):
       $variant_options[] = $value; // loop through...
   endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: Interesting, didnt know you could do that. Question if you don't mind can I pass more options to the variant_option array through the form itself?

Comment: @user1701398 What do you mean more options? You can add as many <input type="text" name="variant_option[]"> as you want and they will then post to the form handler... But each ONE input field can only contain ONE value of course.

Comment: Well eventually I want to allow more then one variant title, and each title will have my options... like size will have sizes and color will have colors. I mean name="variant_option[title_id=1]" Would that be possible?

Comment: Yes but not that way, either use several input field arrays or use multidimensional arrays ie <input type="text" name="variant_option[size][]"> and <input type="text" name="variant_option[color][]">